If I accept all cookies, why is it not saved that I have accepted all cookies?
Every single time I go to a stack exchange website, I am prompted to accept cookies.
Why does this decision not get stored in a cookie? Why do you have to ask me every single time, and no matter what decision I pick, my experience remains the same?

Does this answer your question? The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up (In short, this is an intermittent glitch that's been happening for years.)

@F1Krazy the original bug is wrongly marked as completed, meaning staff won't even try to give it another look. I have cleared the close votes here and reopened, to give it a chance to be really fixed, slim as it may be. The most annoying part is the developer ignoring all comments, but that no surprise and not really related to anything.

That other link was a bug, and it was fixed, but it has come back again over the last few months.  The preference is indeed saved, but it is lost when your login expires.  So every few weeks when you get automatically logged out, the cookie popup appears again, and it doesn't go away even after you log in, which is very annoying.
